# Advice for nhibernate to hibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate, c#-4.0

Hey, 
 I'm looking for any advice about Nhibernate write/read hibernate, across a db from c# to Java. Anything appreciated. Would fluent automappings, may not map that well, but thinking staying closer to the orginal grain, and using simple mapping classes. Better chance of a good 1:1 map?

Any advice glady welcome.

Bob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluent Automapper can export the hbm mapping files. These will likely work with Hibernate with some minor tweaks.
Check this link out http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_configuration#Exporting_mappings